# Amending existing script collapsible-list

Tags: jquery, list, toggle, accordion, collapsable

Evening.

I'm looking at this script **[collapsible-list](https://github.com/sebastien-roch/collapsible-list)** and was hoping someone could help me amend it slightly.

There is a live demo on this page : **[HERE](http://sebastien-roch.github.io/collapsible-list/demo.html)** and I've created a JFiddle **[HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/b6hB5/)**

Currently when the page loads a all sections are fully expanded, is there any way to start the script with them collapsed ?

Is there anyway to only show one expanded section at a time ? ie: If A is shown and I click on B, then B should open and A should close.

How would I add a border around the  entries ? So when closed nothing is shown only the header, but when expanded a 2px border is shown around the correct  section ?

So far I've managed to get it to load with the headers collapsed by adding :

```
allElements.hide();
```

To :

```
        function init() {
            allElements = mainUl.find('> ul > li, ol > li');
            headers = getHeaders();

            allElements.hide();

            setHeadersClickHandler();
            setApi();
            if (options.search !== false) {
                setSearchField();
            }
        }
```

This works BUT to expand a header section I have to double click on it, not single.. any way to do it with a single click ?

I've tried to make it only show one header section at a time by adding the following :

```
var elem = $(this).next('.header')
$('.header').not(elem).hide();
```

To :

```
function expandHeader(header) {
return showListElements(findHeadersList(header).find('> li'))
.done(function() {
header.removeClass('collapsed');
var elem = $(this).next('.header')
$('.header').not(elem).hide();
});
}
```

But this just deleted all the headers when one was clicked !

I'm not sure how to add the border to the UL when expanded. I'd like it to look like this :
[image: Border]

I hope someone can help me with this.
Many Thanks

** UPDATE **

I've got the border appearing and hiding as the UL expands and collapses using :

```
    function collapseHeader(header) {
        return hideListElements(findHeadersList(header).find('> li'))
            .done(function() {
                 $(this).parent().css({"border-width":"0px"});
                header.addClass('collapsed');
            });
    }

    function expandHeader(header) {
        return showListElements(findHeadersList(header).find('> li'))
            .done(function() {
                $(this).parent().css({"border-width":"2px"});
                header.removeClass('collapsed');
            });
    }
```

However when I search if a section contains no matches the UL is closed but the border is still visible. Anyway around that ?

Comment: Resolved using advise from here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23469636/show-and-hide-elements