# Show and hide elements

Tags: jquery, html, show-hide

I've managed to get my menu system working which now shows and hides sections when they are clicked on.

I've also added a search feature to this and that works as well.

Full working version is available on this **[JFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ECTv9/1/)**

Each section is made as follows :

```
<li><a href="#" id="show" name="heada"><h3>&nbsp;Section 1</h3></a>
<div class="slider" style="display:block; display:none;">
    <a href="">Section 1 - Item 1</a><br/>
    <a href="">Section 1 - Item 2</a><br/>
    <a href="">Section 1 - Item 3</a><br/>
    <a href="">Test</a><br/>
</div>
</li>
```

The slight issue I have is when searching I don't want to lose the section headers. eg :

```
<li><a href="#" id="show" name="heada"><h3>&nbsp;Section 1</h3></a>
<li><a href="#" id="show" name="heada"><h3>&nbsp;Section 2</h3></a>
<li><a href="#" id="show" name="heada"><h3>&nbsp;Section 3</h3></a>
```

Currently the search returns the correct results, but the headers are gone.

Is there anyway to keep the headers visible ?

The `class="slider"` applies a border section entries, if there are no entries returned from the search can we hide the entire `DIV` keeping the header visible, similar to how the toggle show/hide currently works. ?

and finally when searching, if I delete anything from the search field it doesn't update the page to show the new results.

I'm assuming this is because I've hidden them and I'm not re showing them, but I'm not sure how.

Comment: Please post the relevant code in the question, not just as a jsfiddle link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AS per your requirement, please check the link

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2249E/4/)

There was space in div because of `<br/>` element. After removing this, you are able to reduce the border as the items hide.

For creating menu, you must use the elements `<ul><li>` and link inside `<li>` This will give you alignment as you required.

Comment: Thanks, this seems to work fine but if the div has an empty result then the border is still shown. Any way to hide the border is there is nothing in the DIV ?

Comment: Hi, I have updated the jsfiddle. please check the below link: 

http://jsfiddle.net/2249E/5/

Answer (score 2):

I think this is you are asking.

Updated code:

```
$("a:not([name='heada'])").each(function () {

        // If the list item does not contain the text phrase fade it out
        if ($(this).text().search(new RegExp(filter, "i")) < 0) {
            $(this).hide().closest(".slider").hide();

            // Show the list item if the phrase matches and increase the count by 1
        } else {
            $(this).show().closest(".slider").show();
            count++;
        }
});
```

Example: [JFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bMJ79/4/)

Comment: Thanks this works well. One quick question if the search field is empty or I delete the entry in the search field is there anyway to close the sections so just the headers as shown as per the original page load ?

Comment: Using you JFiddle example, If I enter item then only sections 2 & 3 expand to show results, yet section 1 has entries matching item. Any ideas ?

Comment: Sorted the closing the headers is the search field is empty : `if (filter.length==0) $('.slider').hide(); `

Answer (score 0):

Add a class to every section header
For Eg:

```
<a href="#" id="show" class="headTag" name="heada"><h3>&nbsp;Section 1</h3></a>
```

and then the keyup function close, just add :

```
$(".headTag").show();
```